# How to set new field using the field inside of document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

There is a document below.

```
{
   price: 10000
}
```

And I want to add a new field using the existing field.

```
{
   price: 10000,
   vat: 1000, // price*0.1
}
```

So, I made a query for executing in the shell.
But it doesn't work. Could you give me some advice? Thank you for reading it.

```
db.getCollection('test').updateMany({},{$set:{'vat': "$price" * 0.1}})
```

$mul operator doesn't work for this case, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use aggregate update

```
db.collection.update({},
[//aggregate update
  {
    $set: {
      vat: {
        "$multiply": [ //aggregate operator
          "$price",
          0.1
        ]
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  "multi": true,
  "upsert": false
})
```

[sample](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wbxip4tYGM1)

Comment: Thank you so much. It works well. Coud I ask you one more thing? It is saved by double type , but I want to save this int(32)type. I know "NumberInt(x)" operator, but not knowing how to apply this in the aggregate.

Comment: You could try $convert and make sure the operator that you try supported in aggregate update.